# margin-left only moving one item to the left, not the whole row

Tags: jquery, css, carousel

On hover on each carousel item, I'm using jQuery to add `-50px` so the whole row shifts left. Unfortunately, only one item shifts left. It's not the amount of margin, because if I add -200px it still does the same thing. Could anyone shed any light on why the whole row isn't shifting `-50px`?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".carousel-item img").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).prev().css('margin-left', '-50px')
  });
  $(".carousel-item img").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).prev().css('margin-left', '0px')
  });
});
```

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  background-color: #696969;
}

a.controls {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 6em;
  background: #000;
  width: 80px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

a.controls:nth-of-type(1) {
  height: 240.625px;
  top: 120px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

a.controls:nth-of-type(2) {
  height: 240.625px;
  top: 120px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item.active,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-next,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
  display: flex;
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item-right.active,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-next {
  transform: translateX(25%);
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item-left.active,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
  transform: translateX(-25%);
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item-right,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-left {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.carousel-item:not(.active) {
  display: none !important;
}

.carousel-item .active {
  display: block !important;
}

.carousel-inner {
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.item-img {
  object-fit: cover;
  position: relative;
  align-self: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 3px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 899;
}

.item-img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3);
  /*margin: 0 70px 0 70px;*/
  margin-right: 50px;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 950;
}

.item-img:not(:hover) {
  z-index: 950;
}

.item {
  height: 240.625px !important;
}

.item__details {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  transition: 450ms opacity;
}

.item__details:before {
  content: '▶';
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  margin-top: -18px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
}

.item__details:after {
  margin-top: -25px;
  margin-left: -25px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 3px solid #ecf0f1;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 1;
}

.item_title {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.item:hover.item__details {
  opacity: 1;
}

.add-m {
  margin-right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>




<div class="container-fluid text-center my-3 p-0">
  <div class="row mx-auto my-auto">
    <h2 class="text-center" style="color:white;">Social Media</h2>
    <div id="ld_Carousel" class="carousel slide w-100" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner w-100" role="listbox">
        <!-- SET 1 -->
        <div class="carousel-item item active">
          <img class="d-block col-2 img-fluid item-img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-1.jpg">
          <img class="d-block col-2 img-fluid item-img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-1.jpg">
          <img class="d-block col-2 img-fluid item-img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-1.jpg">
          <img class="d-block col-2 img-fluid item-img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-1.jpg">
          <img class="d-block col-2 img-fluid item-img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-1.jpg">
          <img class="d-block col-2 img-fluid item-img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-1.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev controls" href="#ld_Carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next controls" href="#ld_Carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is working the way you have it programmed. When the mouse hovers over an image the previous element is moved (the previous element is the image before it). You need to move ALL the images.

Comment: if you change ```$(this)``` to ```$('.carousel-item img.d-block')``` will move all image its viable....or can select any selector or condtion for that, but that what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Your script shifts one image, because you target only one carousel element by `$(this).prev()`. To shift the whole row, instead, you could use `$(this).closest(".carousel-item")`.

Your script would look like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".carousel-item img").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).closest(".carousel-item").css('margin-left', '-50px')
  });
  $(".carousel-item img").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).closest(".carousel-item").css('margin-left', '0px')
  });
});
</script>
```